# Problem with align*

Tags: align

I want to create the following:

[image]

So I wrote this code:

```
\begin{align*}
n & = & 3: S_3={\{1,2,3}\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets} & : & \phi,{\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{1,3}\}\\
n & = & 4 :S_4={\{1,2,3,4}\} \\
\textnormal{Subsets} & : & \phi, {\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{4}\}, {\{1,3}\}, {\{1,4}\}, {\{2,4}\}\\
n & = & 5: S_5={\{1,2,3,4,5}\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets} & : & \phi, {\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{4}\},  {\{1,3}\}, {\{1,4}\}, {\{2,4}\},\\
& &{\{5}\}, {\{1,5}\}, {\{2,5}\}, {\{3,5}\}, {\{1,3,5}\}
\end{align*}
```

But the result was this:

[image]

How can I fix it? Any hint?

Comment: remove the `&` after each `=` the usage in `align` is `&=` not `&=&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I think that I shouldn't use the align* at all, because I need 3 columns, first aligned right, middle aligned center, and the third one aligned left, and I have to find a way to put this at the center of the page!

Comment: Perhaps you’d want to use the environment `array` in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn’t use double `&` for alignment in `align` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
n &= 3: S_3={\{1,2,3}\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets}&: \varnothing,{\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{1,3}\}\\
n &= 4 :S_4={\{1,2,3,4}\} \\
\textnormal{Subsets}&: \varnothing, {\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{4}\}, {\{1,3}\},
{\{1,4}\}, {\{2,4}\}\\
n &= 5: S_5={\{1,2,3,4,5}\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets}&: \varnothing, {\{1}\}, {\{2}\}, {\{3}\}, {\{4}\},
{\{1,3}\}, {\{1,4}\}, {\{2,4}\},\\
&{\{5}\}, {\{1,5}\}, {\{2,5}\}, {\{3,5}\}, {\{1,3,5}\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Bonus: use `\varnothing` from package `amssymb` for your empty sets. Using phi just puzzles the reader.

Comment: +1 for spotting `\phi` I'd missed that:-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a different rendering, but it's not difficult to obtain also the original one, with the correction that the colons shouldn't be spaced (unless you're French).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
n=3{:}\quad                & S_3=\{1,2,3\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad & \emptyset,\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,3\}\\
n=4{:}\quad                & S_4=\{1,2,3,4\} \\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad & \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\}\\
n=5{:}\quad                & S_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad & \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\},  \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\},\\
                           & \{5\}, \{1,5\}, \{2,5\}, \{3,5\}, \{1,3,5\}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n={}&3{:}\quad S_3=\{1,2,3\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad &\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,3\}\\
n={}&4{:}\quad S_4=\{1,2,3,4\} \\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad &\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\}\\
n={}&5{:}\quad S_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
\textnormal{Subsets:}\quad &\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\},  \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,4\},\\
                           &\{5\}, \{1,5\}, \{2,5\}, \{3,5\}, \{1,3,5\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `{\{1}\}` has useless braces that make for difficult reading and could cause problems in other cases: `\{1\}` is the correct input.

Comment: in the second instance why the `{}` before the `=` with the `&` after?  perhaps in case the *n* value goes to two digits?  (and just after i got through explaining to someone else why `{}` isn't needed when the operator follows the `&` ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The alignment point is the left edge of `3` `\emptyset` and so on, so `{}` is necessary for getting the spacing of `=` right.

Comment: urk.  got it.  (i'm a bit brain dead.  finally finished unpacking boxes necessitated by temporarily unloading all office shelves for the semiannual cubicle cleaning.  if i never move again, it will be too soon.)

Comment: it finally struck me that you are using the slashed zero rather than `\varnothing`.  if you can give me a compelling reason for this decision, i can take it to the unicode committee, who have absolutely refused to accept this as a variant form with the "empty set" meaning.  they are wrong, but hard to convince.  please send off line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I simply dislike `\varnothing`, it's more a plumber's symbol. You can show the committee members tons of math books that use the “slashed zero”.

Comment: not good enough.  i've done that.  the chief editor is a linguist, not a mathematician.  he claims this is just a zero with a slash.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't know what to say: if somebody denies the evidence…